# Highcharts Redraw Issue: Line not consistently drawing on update

Tags: highcharts

I am experiencing an issue with Highcharts where the redraw event seems to be firing, but the line is not consistently drawing when the "Update Series" button is clicked. The behavior is inconsistent – it draws the line once, then doesn't draw it, and then draws it again (Alternatively)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

https://jsfiddle.net/wtncd56k/

- Click on the "Update Series" button. (for more than 2-3 times to see the behavior)

**Expected Behavior:**
The line should redraw every time the "Update Series" button is clicked.

**Actual Behavior:**
The line redraws inconsistently – once redrawn with effects from start, and once it doesn't.

```
Highcharts
```

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, referencing this simplified demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1nky4drf/ , are you indicating that the animation doesn't trigger on the second click but does so on the third click?

Comment: @magdalena yes exactly

Comment: I reported a bug that you can track here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20183 ; Temporarily, here is the workaround proposal: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/udohp5n1/